# How to find the points of intersection in a curve and a line

Tags: quadratics, curves

The equation of a curve is $$ y=8\sqrt x -2x $$
We have to find the values of $x$ at which the line $y = 6$ meets the curve

I tried equating them and doing using the quadratic formula like this:
$$ 8\sqrt x -2x = 6 $$
$$ 64x + 4x^2 = 36 $$
$$ 4x^2 + 64x -36 = 0 $$

The answer to the question is $x=9, x=1$ but after solving this quadratic, I'm getting a completely different answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you squared the left side of your equation, you left out the "middle terms": $ \ (a-b)^2 \ \neq \ a^2 + b^2 \ , \ \text{but} \ a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \ . $ You will have an easier time getting rid of the square-root if you write $ \ 8 \sqrt{x} \ = \ 6 + 2x \ $ , square both sides and then simplify the equation before solving it.

Comment: Doing it with this method, I got $ 4x^2 -64x +36 = 0 $

Comment: Solving this still isn't giving me $ x=9, x=1 $

Comment: You left out the middle terms again:  it's $ \ 4x^2 \ + \ 24x \ + \ 36 \ = \ 64x \ $ .

Comment: Ohh, I get it now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Leaving out the middle terms in a "binomial-square" is unfortunately a very common algebra mistake.  Beware of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$ not $a^2+b^2$ as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Differently from the previous comments, I propose another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

\begin{align*}
8\sqrt{x} - 2x = 6 & \Longleftrightarrow x - 4\sqrt{x} + 3 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - \sqrt{x}) - (3\sqrt{x} - 3) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} - 1) - 3(\sqrt{x} - 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt{x} - 3)(\sqrt{x} - 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt{x} = 3)\vee(\sqrt{x} = 1)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x = 9)\vee(x = 1)
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!